# How do I raise list element in dict value to power of x?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, operation

I am a beginner in Python and have several exercises to resolve.

One of these is:

"Define a dictionary w/ keys "abc", "xyz" and values [1, 2, 3] and [9, 10, 11];
iterate over all values (lists) and raise to the power of 4 each element of each list and print to screen"

...and I am bit lost. I could define a function that raises the power of each element in a list, but I do not know how to do it in a dictionary :(

This is where I am stuck:

```
dex = {"abc":[1,2,3],"xyz":[9,10,11]}
for x in dex.values():
     print(x)
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? you said you know how to do it for a list. `x` in your code is a list

Comment: @DeepSpace thanks for the clue so I just had to loop the elements in the list again I guess. I didn't know I could have a For inisde another For but I appreciate the teaching by questioning :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's nested you could use a loop in a loop to get each item of each list, like this:

```
dex = {"abc":[1,2,3],"xyz":[9,10,11]}
for x in dex.values():
     for el in x:
         print(el**4)
```

or using dict and list comprehension:

```
dex = {"abc":[1,2,3],"xyz":[9,10,11]}
dex = {k: [el**4 for el in v] for k, v in dex.items()}
print(dex)
```

Comment: I didn't know I could have another for loop in my existing one sorry I am very new and it is all very confusing/ Thank you!

Comment: @CatalinAgarbiceanu Welcome, you can have as many nested loop or if conditions as you wish :)

Answer (score 0):

This way should work, if you can use dict comprehensions. It uses `map`, which applies a function to each elem in a list.

```py
my_dict = {"abc": [1, 2, 3], "xyz": [9, 10, 11]}
new_dict = {key: list(map(lambda x: x ** 4, val)) for key, val in my_dict.items()}
```

Here, we map a function that raises each item in the list to a power.

Comment: Why do you use map/lambda instead of list comprehension. Does it have advantages or just another way of doing it?

Comment: @David imo it’s a bit easier to see what’s happening. I dont think theres any major performance difference, no, but they do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to present the output, this might work for you:

```
dex = {"abc": [1,2,3], "xyz": [9,10,11]}
print([[e**4 for e in lst] for lst in dex.values()])
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 16, 81], [6561, 10000, 14641]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```py
dex = {"abc":[1,2,3],"xyz":[9,10,11]}

def print_exp (dic) :
    for i,j in dic.items() :
        if isinstance(j,list):
            for n in j :
                print(n**4)
            
print_exp(dex)
```

This one is with a function definition.

Without function definition you can achieve this by :

```py
dex = {"abc":[1,2,3],"xyz":[9,10,11]}


for i,j in dex.items() :
    if isinstance(j,list):
        for n in j :
            print(n**4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the index (or the power) stays constant, the magic method `__rpow__` can be used to chain the operations: `a**4` <--> `int.__pow__(a, 4)` <--> `int.__rpow__(4, a)`

```
dex = {"abc":[1,2,3],"xyz":[9,10,11]}

pows = [list(map(int(4).__rpow__, l)) for l in dex.values()]

print(pows)
```

Output

```
[[1, 16, 81], [6561, 10000, 14641]]
```